# How can I mix arabic two counter styles in caption formatting?

Tags: captions, subfloats, labels, subcaption, subfig

I am hoping to mix two counter styles ( arabic numerals and lower case letters) for the caption formatting as shown in the subsequent exemple:
[image: exemple]

Comment: Yes, it is so helpful. I didn't use \subfigure, I used \subfloat, it's a little different but I just tested it and it's working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you use the subfig or subcaption package version of \subfloat?  Not that it matters.  Both use `\thesubfigure`.

Comment: no @JohnKormylo I didn't use subfig or subcaption packages of \subfloat, I didn't need to.